# Ajax Call : processing data before appending to view

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

My page has XML based Objects loading as per following process

1. On Page load data is loaded in xml format in Dashboard_model.php
2. Upon calling the method in Objects controller data is further passed to XML Parser
3. XML Parser returns the result and its set back in Objects controller and then passed to view
4. View Loops on objects,does perform different operations  such as base64decode ,
   json_dcoded, explodes the strings etc and assign indexes and then its presented on the page :

Now I have to apply AJAX Search to this page and I am not sure on keyup event on a search field how can I refresh the view based on returned data

i am sending ajax query , receiving data but how to append the updated data to the page since result has to be processed as per above steps and cant be appended directly to DOM .

Dashboard Model ::

```
public function object_listing_general($object, $creator_id=false,$subtopic_id=false,$title=false,$description=false,$tags=false,
                                       $type_id=false,    $search_start_date=false,$search_end_date=false, $search_page_number=false,       $search_string_in=false,$order_by=false){
    $data = array(
        'r'                          =>  'search',
        '_object'                    =>  $object,
        '_api_key'                   =>  '....',
        '_usage_type'                =>  'Detailed',
        '_user_id'                   =>  '',
        '_title'                     =>  '',
        '_description'               =>  '',
        '_tags'                      =>  '',
        '_search_end_date'           =>  '',
        '_search_start_date'         =>  '',
        '_search_fuzzy'              =>  1,
        '_search_page_number'        =>  '',
        '_search_results_per_page'   =>  3,
        '_search_string_in'          => '',
         '_order_by'                  =>  '',
        '_search_results_per_page'   =>  4,
    );
    $send_data = http_build_query($data);
    $string= 'urlhere.com/objects?'.$send_data;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    return $server_output;
}
```

**My Controller:**

```
function  tabs_content($object){
    $creator_id= $this->session->userdata['logged_in']['id'];
    $subtopic_id='';
    $description='';
    $tags='';
    $type_id='';
    $search_start_date='';
    $search_end_date='';
    $search_page_number=1;
    $search_page_number='';
    $order_by='';
    $title='';
    $search_string_in='';
    $search= $this->dashboard_model->object_listing_general($object);
    $data=array();
    return json_decode($data->result,true);
}

   public function get_questions(){
       $data['questions'] = $this->tabs_content('Question');
       $this->load->view('admin/templates/main', $data);
   }
```

**View**

```
<div class="questions" >

    <?php
    $question_page_count = 0;
    $question_pages_xml = array ();
    $answers_xml = array();

    $answer_key_xmls = array ();


    foreach ($questions as $ques){
        $question_page_count++;
        $xml_parts = explode('||', base64_decode($ques['object_io_components']));
        $question_part = $xml_parts[0];
        $answer_key_part = $xml_parts[1];
        $answer_detail_part = $xml_parts[2];

        $mxfile_content = new SimpleXMLElement(base64_decode($ques['question_xml']));
        $anwer_file_content = new SimpleXMLElement(base64_decode($ques['question_xml']));

        $question_part = str_replace("<question>", "", $question_part);
        $question_part = str_replace("</question>", "", $question_part);
        $question_part = base64_decode($question_part);

        $question_xml_combo = array ();
        $question_xml_combo['xml'] = (string) $question_part;
        $question_xml_combo['qid'] = $ques['object_id'];
        $question_xml_combo['title'] = $ques['title'];
        $question_xml_combo['description'] = $ques['description'];
        $question_pages_xml[] = $question_xml_combo;
        $answer_key_part = base64_encode($answer_key_part);
        $answer_detail_part = substr($answer_detail_part, strpos($answer_detail_part, '<answer_explanation_container label=" ">')+39);
        $answer_detail_part = substr($answer_detail_part, 0, strpos($answer_detail_part, '</answer_explanation_container>'));
        $answer_detail_part = base64_decode($answer_detail_part);
        $answer_el = array();
        $answer_el['qid'] = $ques['object_id'];
        $answer_el['xml'] =  $answer_detail_part;
        $answers_xml[] = $answer_el;
        $answer_key_el = array();
        $answer_key_el['qid'] = $ques['object_id'];
        $answer_key_el['xml'] =  $answer_key_part;
        $answer_key_xmls[] = $answer_key_el;

       // $question_pages_xml[] = $ques['question_xml'];
        ?>

        <div id="question_page_<?php echo $question_page_count;?>" data-type="question" data-ids="<?php echo $question_page_count;?>"
             data-xml='<?php echo $ques['question_xml'];?>' class="box_styled_container" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragThis(event)">

            <div class="icon_plus_container">
                <div class="tx-info">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#"><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/icon-10.png"></a></li>
                        <li><a id="note_plus_<?php echo $note_page_count;?>" href="#" class="insert_note_page"  ><img src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/icon-20.png"></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <img class="thumb_book" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/books/notes.jpg">
            <p class="box_para">added<?php echo $ques['title'];?></p>
            <p class="box_para"><?php echo $ques['description'];?></p>
        </div>
        <?php


    }
    ?>
```

Now all the process happening here has to be replicated by AJAX search

Comment: Can you add your code to the question?

Comment: Please show your code that you done.

Comment: okay posting code

Comment: Hi, is it necesary to call ajax for search for loading datas ? why not simply show or hide your divs depending on user input ?

Comment: yes , pagination returns 10 records for view at a time and of course  new records are required to be loaded on search input